# Joomla lower version to higher version

Tags: joomla

Have uploaded joomla higher version to the existing site which has lower version.. so am getting error

jtablesession::Store Failed
DB function failed with error number 1054
Unknown column 'client_id' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_session`

any suggetion how to retrive it back or to remove this bug??

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more specific about versions?

If all changes are within 1.5.x then you can visit http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=index and find something...

Upgrade from 1.5 to 1.6 is not possible for now. You need to reinstall the system

1.0.x->1.5.x: http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for ur reply it may be joomla version 1.. what i have done is just uploaded latest version of joomla which i was using in local host..

Comment: 1.0.x is the version i uploaded as i discussed earlier.

Comment: You will need to do the http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_1.0.x_to_1.5_Stable as Semyon suggested. You cannot simply upload the code, this was a major upgrade.